# position fixed background height 100%

Tags: html, css

I need a background all over my page. How can i solve that. The problem is by don't using `position: fixed` the background will be not visible if my content grows.

```
<body>
   <div id="Bgr"></div>
   ...
</body>

#Bgr
{
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  background: url('../images/content-background.png') repeat-y 0, 0;
}
```

***Update: I've already a different background in body and my html, body is 100% height***

Comment: this article by Chris Coyier may help you: http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/ I hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

ensure the body CSS is window size. Common overlook.

Add

```
body {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i can put both images into body since IE10 etc. this solves my problem, too.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use `absolute` for this kind of thing:

```
#Bgr
{
    position: absolute;
    background: url('../images/content-background.png') repeat-y 0, 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```